# A person who travels from place to place without good reason

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for the best word for a person who is continually moving from place to place without good reason, job or fixed home.

Comment: Possible overlap: [What do you call a group of people that move a lot?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29078/)

Comment: @GEdgar — They are talking about *migration*, not *adventure*.

Comment: @dino: If you're looking for an adventure word, you should try using *adventurer*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Drifter** is probably the best fit here, as it doesn't have too many connotations, as *nomad*, *vagabond*, and *itinerant* do.

Naturally, it must be added that the context will ultimately determine the best word-choice.  *Tramp*, *nomad*, *vagabond* or even *adventurer* might well be better words; the choice depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks for thought! I thing drifter is better. But is it good for  UK English as well?

Comment: As far as I know, it is.

Comment: I would argue that drifter has plenty of connotations, few of them positive. I wouldn't really want my daughter dating someone who was described as a drifter (granted, right now I wouldn't want my daughter dating anyone, since she's currently three years old). It certainly fits the meaning in the original question, though.

Comment: @Nicholas - you meant that `drifter` is the best fit in the original question or not... i ask because i really didn't get it :)

Comment: Yes, I think drifter is the best fit for the original question--"a person is continually moving from place to place without good reason, job or fixed home." The question didn't state whether or not any other connotations, whether positive or negative, were desirable. "Drifter" is an excellent fit for the definition given, and unlike "hobo" or "bum" it doesn't necessarly mean "homeless" or "poor," but definitely has some negative connotations.

Answer (score 8):

Nouns, in order of closeness to your specifications:

1. Vagabond
2. Vagrant
3. Drifter
4. Hobo
5. Nomad
6. Bohemian

Adjectives that you may use to describe a person as such:

1. Itinerant
2. Transient

Comment: What about `drifter`? I heard it as well...

Comment: I am confirming the word with an answer.

Comment: Vagabond was the first word that came to my mind.

Comment: Just wooow! You English people has a lot of words for travelers..

Answer (score 4):

- wanderer
- seeker
- rambler
- traveler
- wayfarer
- itinerant (can be used as a noun)

Answer (score 3):

*peripatetic*
I remember the word from [Julian Assange's trial](http://nymag.com/daily/intel/2010/12/judge_denies_appeal_julian_ass.html)

> The judge expressed his own concerns over Assange's rich and powerful supporters, like Australian documentarian John Pilger... The one laugh at the hearing this morning came when the judge scoffed at using Pilger as a surety since he was just "another *peripatetic* (italics added) Australian." Even Assange cracked a smile at that one.

Answer (score 2):

Rover, Wanderer, Nomad, Vagabond, call me what you will.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking vagrant, but since it's already been said, how about bum?

Answer (score 1):

It has so become associated with a popular musical group that nobody mentioned:

[**Rolling Stone**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rolling_stone)

> Definition of *rolling stone* in English:
>
> **rolling stone**
>
> NOUN
>
> A person who is unwilling to settle for long in one place.
>
> *‘he was a rolling stone, with no ties to anyone or anyplace’*

(Although I personally do not condone the Oxford English Dictionary's use of ‘any place’ in an example.)

Comment: My goodness, this is an old post. No idea why it came up again, but happy to add something extra.

Answer (score -1):

All the sensible recommendations seem to have been made, so how about King of the Road? You might also consider road scholar if you're looking for something humorous.