# A person who moves from place to place in search of opportunity

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I move in search of opportunity.

When I was young, my father worked for the government, and we moved because of his posting.

Then I moved to a different city so I could get cheap education. Later, I moved to 
 yet another city to get a job. I have lived outside my home state more than inside, which makes me wonder if I can call it my "home state" at all.

*Is there a (single) word for people like me who move in search of opportunities?*

I found in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/people-who-travel) the phrase 'bird of passage' which is a hypernym, but not an exact match:

> *bird of passage* [noun] [literary]
>
> someone who keeps moving from one place to another

Comment: P.S.: I am aware of 'nomad', and that is not the word I am looking for. Besides, nomads move in search of food for their animals, which is different kind of move. correct me if I misunderstand, Thanks

Comment: The fixed expression / compound noun 'economic migrant' may be as close as you can get.

Comment: There's another meaning to *nomad* apart from the primary, more common one. Look up the OxfordDictionary online (now **Lexico** https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nomad). Note the example sentences, too. Good Luck.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Migrants usually do not keep moving about.

Comment: @Kris Migratory birds do. But that's a reason for not submitting this as an 'answer'. // It always baffles me that responses can come while one is still composing a post here. A bit frightening. I wonder if they're watching us?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Migratory birds are so called because they migrate from one place to another (and back), not every where all the time.

Comment: @Kris Some species of animals (eg Monarch butterflies) migrate in stages, sometimes not completing (for the entire cohort) a full circuit. I've just thrown in this as an obviously closely related phenomenon, and indicated that it is a broadening too far ... but it's not way off target. Possibly a hyponym of the word OP is after (if it exists).

Comment: The related thread [What do you call ... people that move a lot?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29078/what-do-you-call-a-group-of-people-that-move-a-lot/29084#29084) gives hypernyms such as 'itinerant'. 'Peripatetic' usually implies travellings from a home base.

Comment: Seeker of fortune?

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider **[itinerant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/itinerant)**:

> working in one place for a comparatively short time and then moving on to work in another place

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you might be looking for,

## Transient

> /ˈtranzɪənt/
>
> noun
>
> > : a person who is staying or working in a place for a short time only.

Some example sentences -

> ‘*Thanks to their dazzling diversity of color, furtive nature, and
> transient presence, warblers, and their fellow neotropical migrants
> monopolize spring birding.*’

---

> ‘*Since 1999, the territorial government has been coping with hundreds
> of staff vacancies and a highly transient workforce - and few
> employees who want to stay in their jobs for long.*’

---

> ‘*While the furthest camping section is the refuge of transient
> workers looking for an affordable place to stay, tourists are most
> likely to make use of the cabins and dorms.*’

---

> ‘*Among other consequences, this has meant that the tourism industry
> has not been able to adequately access transient workers because there
> is nowhere for them to stay.*’

---

> ‘*It is believed that permitting foreign expatriates to own their own
> properties encourages increased longevity of stay and contributes to a
> more less transient economic environment.*’

([From Oxford (now Lexico)](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/transient))